# Saving list with 120 dataframes (11.1 GB)

Tags: r, list

I have a huge list called lista_meses that contains 120 dataframes (11.1 GB). This list comes from a code that always takes a lot of time to run, so that's why I want to save the result so I don't have to run the code again. Is it possible to save a list this Big?

So far, I have tried with rlist package but I get an rdata file of 5.000.000 KB, which is enormous.

```
list.save(lista_meses, "lista_meses.rdata")
```

.

Any idea of how to save this type of list? Thanks!

Comment: I would try iterating over each list element and writing the data frames individually to a folder in some modern format. A favorite of mine is parquet from the `arrow` package. Then you can iterate over each file in the folder to read and rebuild the list. Just a thought, and not too hard to do.

Comment: I would iterate over the 120 `data.frames` and save as `.csv.gz`, that can compress quite a bit, but still require a good chunk of space because your data is big

Comment: You can use saveRDS to write save the object directly.

Comment: Once you start getting into data that size, having a database can pay dividends: not only can you store all that in one database, but you can query for only specific data and do processing on it in smaller chunks. A "database" can be a full-up server-based (e.g., postgresql, sqlserver, mariadb), or it can be file-based (e.g., sqlite, or the recent duckdb, which claims significant speed improvements over sqlite).

Comment: perhaps have a look at [disk.frame](https://github.com/xiaodaigh/disk.frame)